# Is there an efficient or any way to generate a template from a function parameter

Tags: c++, templates, constexpr

I came across this code that uses a class and function parameter to decide how to handle their data in terms of templates below.

```
class ArrayIntTypes{
    public:
        using value_type = int;
        uint32_t size;
        ArrayIntTypes(){}
        virtual void set(const std::any& val, void* begin){
            value_type _v = std::any_cast<value_type>(val);
            value_type* _beg = (value_type*)begin;
            value_type* _end = (value_type*)end(begin);
            std::for_each(_beg, _end, [_v](auto& val){val = _v;});
        }
        virtual std::shared_ptr<void> make_shared(uint32_t _size){
            size = _size;
            return std::make_unique<value_type[]>(_size);
        }
        virtual void* end(void* ptr){
            value_type* casted = reinterpret_cast<value_type*>(ptr);
            return casted + size;
        }
        virtual const void* cend(const void* ptr){
            const value_type* casted = reinterpret_cast<const value_type*>(ptr);
            return casted + size;
        }
        virtual void* share_from(void* ptr, uint32_t x){
            value_type* casted = reinterpret_cast<value_type*>(ptr);
            return casted + x;
        }
        virtual void transform_function(std::function<int(const int&)> func, const void* my_begin, int* out){
            const value_type* begin  = reinterpret_cast<const value_type*>(my_begin);
            const value_type* end = reinterpret_cast<const value_type*>(cend(my_begin));
            std::transform(begin, end, out, func);
        }   
        virtual void transform_function(std::function<float(const float&)> func, const void* my_begin, float* out){
            throw std::invalid_argument("Int Array cannot do float for transform type");
        }
};

class ArrayFloatTypes : public ArrayIntTypes{
    public:
        using value_type = float;
        ArrayFloatTypes(){}
        void set(const std::any& val, void* begin) override{
            value_type _v = std::any_cast<value_type>(val);
            value_type* _beg = (value_type*)begin;
            value_type* _end = (value_type*)end(begin);
            std::for_each(_beg, _end, [_v](auto& val){val = _v;});
        }
        std::shared_ptr<void> make_shared(uint32_t _size) override {
            size = _size;
            return std::make_unique<value_type[]>(_size);
        }
        void* end(void* ptr) override {
            value_type* casted = reinterpret_cast<value_type*>(ptr);
            return casted + size;
        }
        const void* cend(const void* ptr) override {
            const value_type* casted = reinterpret_cast<const value_type*>(ptr);
            return casted + size;
        }
        void* share_from(void* ptr, uint32_t x) override{
            value_type* casted = reinterpret_cast<value_type*>(ptr);
            return casted + x;
        }
        void transform_function(std::function<float(const float&)> func, const void* my_begin, float* out) override{
            const value_type* begin  = reinterpret_cast<const value_type*>(my_begin);
            const value_type* end = reinterpret_cast<const value_type*>(cend(my_begin));
            std::transform(begin, end, out, func);
        }
        void transform_function(std::function<int(const int&)> func, const void* my_begin, int* out) override{
            throw std::invalid_argument("Float Array cannot do int transform");
        }
};


enum DType {Int, Float};


struct ArrayVoid{
    private:
        std::unique_ptr<ArrayIntTypes> typed;
        std::shared_ptr<void> _vals;
        uint32_t size;
        std::unique_ptr<ArrayIntTypes> get_typed(DType _type){
            switch (_type){
                case Int:
                    return std::make_unique<ArrayIntTypes>();
                case Float:
                    return std::make_unique<ArrayFloatTypes>();
                default:
                    return std::make_unique<ArrayFloatTypes>();
            }
        }
    public:
        DType dtype;
        ArrayVoid(uint32_t _size, DType _type = DType::Float):
            size(_size), 
            _vals(nullptr), 
            typed(get_typed(_type)),
            dtype(_type)
        {
            _vals = this->typed->make_shared(_size);
        }
        uint32_t Size() const {return size;}
        const void* data_ptr() const {return _vals.get();}
        void* data_ptr() {return _vals.get();}
        void operator=(const uint32_t inp){
            typed->set(std::any(inp), begin());
        }
        void operator=(const int inp){
            typed->set(std::any(inp), begin());
        }
        void operator=(const double inp){
            typed->set(std::any(inp), begin());
        }
    
        void operator=(const float inp){
            typed->set(std::any(inp), begin());
        }
        std::shared_ptr<void> share_part(uint32_t index){
            return std::shared_ptr<void>(_vals, typed->share_from(data_ptr(), index));
        }
        void* begin(){
            return data_ptr();
        }
        void* end(){
            return typed->end(data_ptr());
        }
        const void* cbegin() const {
            return data_ptr();
        }
        const void* cend() const {return typed->cend(data_ptr());}
        void transform_function(std::function<float(const float&)> func, float* out) const{
            typed->transform_function(func, _vals.get(), out);
        }
        void transform_function(std::function<int(const int&)> func, int* out) const{
            typed->transform_function(func, _vals.get(), out);
        }


};

//example usage:
void void_shared_iterator(uint32_t x){
    ArrayVoid vals_a(x, DType::Float);
    ArrayVoid vals_b(x , DType::Float);
    vals_b = 2.3;
    float* begin_ptr = reinterpret_cast<float*>(vals_a.begin());
    for(uint32_t i = 0; i < x; ++i){
        *begin_ptr = i;
        ++begin_ptr;
    }
    std::cout<<"vals_a:"<<std::endl;
    std::for_each(reinterpret_cast<const float*>(vals_a.data_ptr()), reinterpret_cast<const float*>(vals_a.data_ptr()) + x, [](auto& val){std::cout<<val<<std::endl;});
    std::cout<<"vals_b:"<<std::endl;
    std::for_each(reinterpret_cast<const float*>(vals_b.data_ptr()), reinterpret_cast<const float*>(vals_b.data_ptr()) + x, [](auto& val){std::cout<<val<<std::endl;});
    vals_a.transform_function([](const float& val){return val + 2.4;}, reinterpret_cast<float*>(vals_a.begin()));
    std::cout<<"vals_a:"<<std::endl;
    std::for_each(reinterpret_cast<const float*>(vals_a.data_ptr()), reinterpret_cast<const float*>(vals_a.data_ptr()) + x, [](auto& val){std::cout<<val<<std::endl;});
}
```

After looking at it, I was curious if there was a way to implement it in a more straightforward fashion. So I came up with something that uses something similar to `std::conditional`, as shown below, but obviously this doesn't work because the `DType` parameter variables are not `constexpr`. However, I wondered if there was a way to do something similar?

```
enum class DType {Int, Float};

template<DType T, class Enable=bool>
struct dtype_conditional { using type = void;};

template<DType T>
struct dtype_conditional<T, typename std::enable_if<T == DType::Float>> {using type = float;};

template<DType T>
struct dtype_conditional<T, typename std::enable_if<T == DType::Int>> {using type = int;};


class ArrayConditional{
    std::shared_ptr<void> _vals;
    size_t _size;
    std::shared_ptr<void> make_shared(size_t size, DType type){
        using value_type = dtype_conditional<type>::type;
        return std::make_unique<value_type[]>(size);    
    }
    template<typename T>
    T* my_begin(){
        return reinterpret_cast<T*>(_vals.get());
    }
    template<typename T>
    const T* my_cbegin() const{
        return reinterpret_cast<const T*>(_vals.get());
    }
    template<typename T>
    T* my_end(){
        return reinterpret_cast<T*>(_vals.get()) + _size;
    }
    template<typename T>
    const T* my_cend(){
        return reinterpret_cast<const T*>(_vals.get()) + _size;
    }
    public:
        const DType dtype;
        ArrayConditional(uint32_t size, const DType _type)
            :_size(size), 
            _vals(make_shared(size, _type)), 
            dtype(_type)
        {}
        uint32_t Size() const {return size;}
        const void* cbegin() const {return _vals.get();}
        void* begin() {return _vals.get();}
        template<typename T>
        void set(const T& val){
            using value_type = dtype_conditional<dtype>::type;
            std::fill(my_begin<value_type>(), my_end<value_type>(), val);   
        }
        template<typename T>
        ArrayConditional& operator=(const T& val){set(val); return *this;}
        void print(){
            using value_type = dtype_conditional<dtype>::type;
            const value_type* cbeg = my_cbegin<value_type>();
            const value_type* cend = my_cend<value_type>();
            std::for_each(cbeg, cend, [](const auto& val){
                        std::cout<<val << " ";
                    });
        }
    
};
```

Is there any way to do something like this without making the `ArrayConditional` class typed? Obviously, there would never really be a reason to do this, I am just curious.

### Updated code with an iterator

So, this isn't exactly what I was hoping to get, where I could actually have each `dtype` differentiated using something like `std::conditional`. However, below I made an iterator where it was able to implement the type `void*` as the iterator pointer. However, by the time it gets to the reference, I do actually have to define a type. Again, it would be a lot easier to just have a way to define `value_type` as I had in the previous code.

```
size_t get_size(DType _t){
    switch(_t){
        case DType::Int:
            return sizeof(int);
        case DType::Float:
            return sizeof(float);
        default:
            return 1;
    }
}


union dtype_ref{
    std::reference_wrapper<float> Float;
    std::reference_wrapper<int> Int;
    dtype_ref(std::reference_wrapper<float> _f)
        :Float(_f)
    {}

    dtype_ref(std::reference_wrapper<int> _i)
        :Int(_i)
    {}
};

struct ArrayConditionalReference{
    dtype_ref data;
    DType _type;
    ArrayConditionalReference(std::reference_wrapper<float> _f)
        :_type(DType::Float),
        data(_f)
    {}
    ArrayConditionalReference(std::reference_wrapper<int> _f)
        :_type(DType::Int),
        data(_f)
    {}
    ArrayConditionalReference& operator=(const float& val){
        switch(_type){
            case DType::Float:
                data.Float.get() = val;
                break;
            case DType::Int:
                data.Int.get() = (int)val;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return *this;
    }
    ArrayConditionalReference& operator=(const int& val){
        switch(_type){
            case DType::Float:
                data.Float.get() = (float)val;
                break;
            case DType::Int:
                data.Int.get() = val;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return *this;
    }
    ArrayConditionalReference& operator=(const ArrayConditionalReference& val){
        switch(_type){
            case DType::Float:
                data.Float.get() = val.item_float();
                break;
            case DType::Int:
                data.Int.get() = val.item_int();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return *this;
    
    }
    ArrayConditionalReference& operator+=(const float& val){
        switch(_type){
            case DType::Float:
                data.Float.get() += val;
                break;
            case DType::Int:
                data.Int.get() += val;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return *this;   
    }
    ArrayConditionalReference& operator+=(const int& val){
        switch(_type){
            case DType::Float:
                data.Float.get() += val;
                break;
            case DType::Int:
                data.Int.get() += val;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return *this;   
    }
    float& item_float(){
        return data.Float.get();
    }
    int& item_int(){
        return data.Int.get();
    }
    const float& item_float() const{
        return data.Float.get();
    }
    const int& item_int() const{
        return data.Int.get();
    }
};


std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const ArrayConditionalReference& val){
    switch(val._type){
        case DType::Float:
            out << val.data.Float.get();
            break;
        case DType::Int:
            out << val.data.Int.get();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return out;
}

class ArrayConditionalItterator{
    public:
        using iterator_category = std::forward_iterator_tag;
        using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
        using reference = ArrayConditionalReference;
        using pointer = void;
        using value_type = void;

        size_t size;
        ArrayConditionalItterator(void* _ptr, const DType _t)
        :m_ptr(_ptr),
        size(get_size(_t)),
        _type(_t)
        {}
        ArrayConditionalItterator& operator++(){
            m_ptr = (void*)(static_cast<uint8_t*>(m_ptr) + size);
            return *this;
        }
        ArrayConditionalItterator operator++(int){
            ArrayConditionalItterator tmp = *this;
            ++(*this);
            return tmp;
        }
        const bool operator==(const ArrayConditionalItterator& b) const{
            return static_cast<const uint8_t*>(m_ptr) == static_cast<const uint8_t*>(b.m_ptr);
        }
        const bool operator!=(const ArrayConditionalItterator& b) const{
            return static_cast<const uint8_t*>(m_ptr) != static_cast<const uint8_t*>(b.m_ptr);
        }
        ArrayConditionalReference operator*() const {
            switch(_type){
                case DType::Float:
                    return ArrayConditionalReference(std::ref(*reinterpret_cast<float*>(m_ptr)));
                case DType::Int:
                    return ArrayConditionalReference(std::ref(*reinterpret_cast<int*>(m_ptr)));
            }
        }

    private:
        void* m_ptr;
        const DType _type;

};


class ArrayConditional{
    std::shared_ptr<void> _vals;
    size_t _size;
    std::shared_ptr<void> make_shared(size_t size, DType type){
        switch(type){
            case DType::Float:
                return std::make_unique<float[]>(size);
            case DType::Int:
                return std::make_unique<int[]>(size);
        }
    }
    public:
        const DType dtype;
        ArrayConditional(uint32_t size, const DType _type = DType::Float)
            :_size(size), 
            _vals(make_shared(size, _type)), 
            dtype(_type)
        {}
        uint32_t Size() const {return _size;}
        const void* data_ptr() const {return _vals.get();}
        void* data_ptr() {return _vals.get();}
        void* data_ptr_end() { return reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(_vals.get()) + (_size * get_size(dtype));}
        const void* data_ptr_cend() const { return reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t*>(_vals.get()) + (_size * get_size(dtype));}
        ArrayConditionalItterator begin(){return ArrayConditionalItterator(data_ptr(), dtype);}
        ArrayConditionalItterator end(){return ArrayConditionalItterator(data_ptr_end(), dtype);}
        void set(const float& val){
            std::fill(begin(), end(), val); 
        }
        void set(const int& val){
            std::fill(begin(), end(), val); 
        }
        ArrayConditional& operator=(const float& val){set(val); return *this;}
        ArrayConditional& operator=(const int& val){set(val); return *this;}
        void print(){
            std::for_each(begin(), end(), [](const auto& val){
                        std::cout<<val << " ";
                    });
            std::cout<<std::endl;
        }
        template<typename T>
        void transform_function(std::function<T(const ArrayConditionalReference&)> func, T* out){
            std::transform(begin(), end(), out, func);
        }
        template<typename T>
        void transform_function(std::function<T(const ArrayConditionalReference&)> func, ArrayConditionalItterator out){
            std::transform(begin(), end(), out, func);
        }   
};
```

Then I ran the following function:

```
void void_shared_iterator(uint32_t x){
    ArrayConditional vals_a(x, DType::Float);
    vals_a = 10.0102f;
    vals_a.print();
    vals_a.transform_function(std::function<float(const ArrayConditionalReference&)>([](const ArrayConditionalReference& val){return val.item_float() + 2.2;}), vals_a.begin());
    vals_a.print();
}

int main(){
    void_shared_iterator(11);
    return 0;
}
```

Then I got the following output:

```
10.0102 10.0102 10.0102 10.0102 10.0102 10.0102 10.0102 10.0102 10.0102 10.0102 10.0102
12.2102 12.2102 12.2102 12.2102 12.2102 12.2102 12.2102 12.2102 12.2102 12.2102 12.2102
```

However, I am wondering if there is away around using this type of iterator and reference class that has to use a union that is much more straightforward?

### A minimal example

Basically, I am just kind of wondering if there is a way to generate a typename using an `enum`. As an example:

```
enum class DType {Int, Float};
void iterate(void* ptr_begin, size_t size, DType type){
  //obviously this doesn't work, because the variable type is a function parameter
  using value_type = std::conditional<type == DType::Int, int, float>::value
  value_type* begin = reinterpret_cast<value_type*>(ptr_begin);
  value_type* end = begin + size;
  for(;begin != end; ++begin){
    *begin += 2;
  }
}
```

This is a very minimal example, I just used the classes above as way to solve it. Obviously this doesn't work.

Comment: Would it be possible to have a rather shorter example?  It’s hard to see which part of this is important, and whether the whole thing is just `std::variant` or so in disguise.

Comment: Please explain what you want to achieve with an [mre]. Need to emphasize that it has to be minimal. To elaborate on what you want to achieve. I don't even get why not just using `std::vector`...

Comment: Obviously you can write `template<DType D> void iterate(void*,std::size_t);` and actually use `std::conditional_t`.  Are you just asking how to make that be a runtime parameter (crucially: from a small, known set)?